# Elastic query to search eliminating spaces from mongodb data C#

Tags: c#, mongodb, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-net

I wanted to know if there is a way to search MongoDB data excluding space. My MongoDB has data such as -

```js
"Element":"Ele1"
"Element":"Ele2"
"Element":"Ele 3"
```

And my search query has string excluding space i.e "Ele1,Ele2,Ele3". So When I pass "Ele3" to my search query it does not return any result. I am using ElasticSearch.net nuget. My code is something like this -

```js
var elResp = await data.MultiSearchAsync(m => m
                    .Query(q => q
                    .Nested(n => n
                    .Path("Element")
                    .Query(qq => qq
                        .Bool(b => b
                            .Must(m1 => m1
                            .Term("Element.keyword", "Ele1")))))))
```

Is there anything I can do or I have to create an extra field in MongoDb which saves Element Value without space. So I can perform check from that. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd achieve the best performance by creating extra field without spaces, however in MongoDB you can just use [$regex](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/) to match both fields with and without spaces.

```
db.collection.find({ "Element": { $regex: /Ele\s*3/ } })
```

where `\s` is a whitespace and `*`means zero or more occurences. The more spaces you predict, the more you should consider adding a field without any spaces (because of performance), but `/E\s*l\s*e\s*3/` will be still working for this case.